# Proxychain not resolving the host

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, torsocks, privoxy

It seems weird...i have installed Tor,Privoxy and Proxychains on my Ubuntu for an experimental purpose..i managed to install it properly and got proxychain to run and resolve `gxxxxe.com` `proxychains firefox www.gxxxxe.com`, today i was exercising on one of the study i made about proxychains i just opened my terminal typed the same thing `proxychains firefox www.gxxxxe.com` but end up in error.it does nothing it just opened the firefox and says server not found and on the terminal it was like

ProxyChains-3.1 (http://proxychains.sf.net)

thats it a single line. no chaining and all happening, i really puzzled should i start anything before i use proxychain or is that any problem with DNS or the Tor circuit i have been trying to connect is down?

on Terminal

```
|DNS-response|: self-repair.mozilla.org does not exist
|DNS-request| support.mozilla.org 
|S-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout
|DNS-response|: support.mozilla.org does not exist
|DNS-request| support.mozilla.org 
|S-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout
|DNS-response|: support.mozilla.org does not exist
```

My conf :`socks5  127.0.0.1 9050` at the end of proxychain config and
`forward-socks5 / 127.0.0.1:9050` at the end of privoxy config.

Comment: how did you configured your internet browser ? kind regards

Comment: hey Gia, i saw it was like "use system proxy setting" but it worked yesterday i don't think the problem has to deal with the browser.

Comment: you might use a proxy-switcher add'on ? Or try to restart Tor, Privoxy and Proxychain.

Comment: No Nothin.i did restart also

Comment: it means when you use your system proxy settings on the browser, you may reach the websites ?

Comment: I think its not necessary to change the browser setting because we use sock to route our traffic.if yes what we will do if we make a TCP request rather than HTTP..i think it ought to deal with DNS

Comment: Should be so in this case. Maybe Wireshark or similar tools might discover some issues ? I don't know well the configuration on your side.

Comment: the thing is it worked but i don't know what was happened over night :) for the very change behavior.

Comment: I'm not sure about but maybe in the proxychain config can be added something like                        cache_peer localhost parent 8118 7 no-query default
Somehow it seems it's a Tor or DNS issue.

Comment: You forgot to turn on the tor service, maybe. Try to turn it on, sudo service tor start, then try again.

Answer (score 1):

To fix all the DNS issues like that I do recommend you to use a local resolver configured for using Tor as a transport, but serving your system as usual. I'm using ISC Bind, works like a charm. Don't fprget to edit `/etc/resolv.conf` and so forth.

Comment: would you eloborate your answer Alex, how can i configure ISC in resolv.conf

Comment: @RichardGeorge just like that `nameserver 127.0.0.1` in the first and ONLY `nameserver` line in it. Actually I'm using one-lined resolv.conf =)

Comment: I have to download and install ISC bind in my system wasn't i? and why tor not working...?

Comment: @RichardGeorge have you configurated the Bind itself? what is your OS? I can help you to config it if you wish

Comment: Ubuntu i am using ...you use fb can we sit on call?

Comment: I'm using (FB)[https://www.facebook.com/avesnin], and Skype too. Skype me aves777. I'm using ubuntu too btw =)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34377/discussion-between-richard-george-and-alexey-vesnin).